# CSS div to extend content onto more lines

Tags: php, css, styles, dreamweaver

I have a php script that returns a list of small images (like thumbprints) that are displayed based on search criteria.

I'd like these images to be displayed on after another until they reach approx 45% across the screen and then if there are more images than will fit in the space, the images continue on to a new line.

I have used CSS to set the following within a div.

```
  .example {
  Float: left;
  Width: 45%;
  }
```

But the images continue beyond the 45%.
If I used the style overlap:scroll; or overlap:hidden, the images stop at 45% and either you can scroll to see the others or they are hidden.

How can I make the images continue onto a new 'line'.

I've tried word-wrap without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you show us the php loop thsta producing the images. Also in your CSS use all lower case for declaration eg`width` not `Width`

Comment: I think it must be the php loop as the CSS is correct. I didn't realise the php would 'override' the CSS- I thought the php result would just fit into the CSS format. I will take a look at the php. Thanks

Comment: The php won't override the CSS. It would more likely be an error in the `html` that is being produced by your `php` loop.

Comment: I'm using dreamweaver for search and php... `code`<table width="100" height="38" border="1"> <?php do { ?>
<tr> <td width="38"><img class='example' src="images/<?php echo $row_getresult['image_name']; ?>.png"/><br>
              </a></td></tr>
              <?php } while ($row_getamenityaccommodation = mysql_fetch_assoc($getamenityaccommodation)); ?>
          </table>`code` This returns a column of images, one after another. How do I alter the code to show images left to right and then onto new line, within the div -css as above ?? Maybe use an array?

Answer (score 1):

the way you describe it it should work just fine.

I made a jsfiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wbh6L/)

images are by default displayed as `inline` elements, if the elements are not images try using `display:inline` on them or `display:inline-block`.

Comment: I agree- it is my php which is the problem - or html!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display:inline-block;` to the element.